# Prove function is complex analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I want to prove that $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is analytic around the origin. I tried using $z=x+iy$ and attempted to express $f$ as $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ to apply the Cauchy Riemann equations, but this is proving to be very cumbersome. Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Start with proving that $g(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$. And $g(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: (Writing the function as a power series seems to be quite helpful)

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Like a Taylor series? How can I take the derivatives before proving it's analyticity?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok that works. A ton of algebra though for the CR equations...

Comment: Forget the Cauchy-Riemann equations. They are usually the worst way to show that a function is holomorphic. Use that sums, products, quotients (where the denominator is not $0$, or more precisely where the denominator does not vanish with higher order than the numerator) and compositions of holomorphic functions are holomorphic, and that the sum of a convergent power series is holomorphic in the disk of convergence. Just expand $e^z-1$ in a power series, divide that by $z$, and hey presto, $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is recognised as an entire holomorphic function. Then take the reciprocal. Done.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you post as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchy-Riemann equations are usually way more cumbersome to prove that a function is holomorphic than other methods. The usually most convenient way to see a function is holomorphic uses that sums, products, quotients (where the denominator is not 0, or more precisely where the denominator does not vanish with higher order than the numerator) and compositions of holomorphic functions are holomorphic, and that the sum of a convergent power series is holomorphic in the disk of convergence. Also, parameter-dependent integrals where the integrand depends holomorphically on the parameter are holomorphic when differentiation under the integral is legitimate.

Here, we can expand $e^z-1$ in a power series:

$$e^z-1 = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right)-1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!},$$

and that can evidently be divided by $z$ without problems, so

$$h(z) := \frac{e^z-1}{z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}$$

is recognised as an entire holomorphic function, with $h(0) = 1 \neq 0$. Thus

$$\frac{z}{e^z-1} = \frac{1}{h(z)}$$

is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Got my upvote privilege :) Here you go!